# java mail - how to retrieve the last replied mail of a sender

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm trying to retrieve the latest mail received in my mail box **from one sender**. I have an issue when a sender reply on one of his emails, for example:

[screenshot of my exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQwug.png)

I want to get the last message received on 04/28 instead of getting the two messages.

In my code, I simply did this to get my messages:

```
defaultFolder = store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("inbox"); 
Message [] msg = defaultFolder.getMessages();
```

Any ideas of how we can get only the latest email of **the same sender** ?

Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is that you need to `Folder.search(SearchTerm)`.  For more information, read the javadocs,

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest recieved email from the folder you can Sort items by using the  [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method, here is a VBA sample (the Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications):

```
Sub SortByDueDate() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
 myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False 
 For Each myItem In myItems 
  MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
 Next myItem 
End Sub
```

So, the first item will be the latest received. As soon as you got the latest item you can iterate over all items in the same conversation. The [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. So, you may get all items from the conversation. Read more about that in the [Obtain and Enumerate Selected Conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/categories-and-conversations/obtain-and-enumerate-selected-conversations) article. For example:

```
void DemoConversation() 
{ 
 object selectedItem = 
 Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; 
 // This example uses only 
 // MailItem. Other item types such as 
 // MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
 // in the conversation. 
 if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 // Cast selectedItem to MailItem. 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 // Determine the store of the mail item. 
 Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent 
 as Outlook.Folder; 
 Outlook.Store store = folder.Store; 
 if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true) 
 { 
 // Obtain a Conversation object. 
 Outlook.Conversation conv = 
 mailItem.GetConversation(); 
 // Check for null Conversation. 
 if (conv != null) 
 { 
 // Obtain Table that contains rows 
 // for each item in the conversation. 
 Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable(); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " + 
 table.GetRowCount().ToString()); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:"); 
 while (!table.EndOfTable) 
 { 
 Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow(); 
 Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"] 
 + " Modified: " 
 + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]); 
 } 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:"); 
 // Obtain root items and enumerate the conversation. 
 Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems 
 = conv.GetRootItems(); 
 foreach (object item in simpleItems) 
 { 
 // In this example, only enumerate MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mail = item 
 as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mail.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Call EnumerateConversation 
 // to access child nodes of root items. 
 EnumerateConversation(item, conv); 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 } 
} 
 
 
void EnumerateConversation(object item, 
 Outlook.Conversation conversation) 
{ 
 Outlook.SimpleItems items = 
 conversation.GetChildren(item); 
 if (items.Count > 0) 
 { 
 foreach (object myItem in items) 
 { 
 // In this example, only enumerate MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 myItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mailItem.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Continue recursion. 
 EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation); 
 } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the idea is getting the latest email from the same sender, when this latter sent an email days ago and then reply again on his email.

Comment: Yes, you can get the source email by navigating through the conversation and checking the sender.

Comment: _if_ your server supports the IMAP sort extension.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your solution @EugeneAstafiev, but I'm treating a lot of emails at the same time, I'm looking for a solution to retrieve the latest email of a thread sent by a person

Comment: A store supports `Conversation` view if the store is a POP, IMAP, or PST store. So, you can use the API shown in the post to get the latest email.